# Batch program to copy file when there is a change in source folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need a batch program that will copy files from source folder to destination folder whenever there is a change(new files added or files modified) in source folder and restart a specific service.

Comment: "I need a batch program" is not an on topic question for this site. Please take the site [tour], and consult the guidance within the [ask] pages.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the help of [xcopy /?](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) using the switch ***/D***

> /D : Copy files changed on or after the specified date.
> If no date is given, copy only files whose
> source date/time is newer than the destination time.

***Syntax :***

```
XCOPY source [destination] [options]
```

---

***Remark :***

So, in this batch file below, if you have any spaces in your directory names, you need to enclose them in double quotes.

---

```bat
@echo off
Set SourceDir="C\My Source\stuff"
Set TargetDir="D:\My Backup\stuff"
xcopy %SourceDir% %TargetDir% /i /d /y /e
```

---

***/D*** : copy only files whose source date/time is newer than the destination time.

***/E*** : To copy everything, including new directories, you should add the `/e` switch

***/Y*** : Suppress prompt to confirm overwriting a file.

***/I*** :   If in doubt always assume the destination is a folder e.g. when the destination does not exist.